# Evitar loop infinito de erros

Tags: delphi, loop

Gostaria de saber se tem como evitar a ocorrencia de loops infinitos de erros no Delphi XE2. Esses erros normalmente são erros criticos de falta de algum arquivo (como DLL) ou sem permissão de acesso a algo.

Utilizo tratamento de exceção, porém em casos muito esporádicos alguns desses erros ocorrem, porém se torna impossível finalizar a aplicação sem ser pelo Gerenciador de Tarefas do Windows, pois ao clicar no OK da mensagem outra aparece.

Alguém tem uma dica de como evitar este loop, nem que para isso seja preciso finalizar a aplicação

Abaixo um exemplo de mensagem:

[image: Exemplo de erro]

Comment: O jeito de evitar esta repetição de exceção em série é entender o que a causa e eliminar esta causa. Se você souber o que causa a exceção, você pode corrigir ou tratar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como citado pelo [@Caffe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46406/evitar-loop-infinito-de-erros/46423#comment93229_46406) em comentário, o correto seria você capturar as [exceções](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Exceptions) lançadas e trata-las. O erro de [Violação de Acesso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6decc55h.aspx) é algo crítico, supondo que exceções do gênero ocorram ao usuário final do seu programa, é certo que você terá problemas futuramente.

Veja o exemplo abaixo onde trata erros específicos.

```
Try
   // Fazer algo aqui.
Except
   On E : EInOutError do 
     // Não é possível alocar memória
     // Tratar esse erro aqui.

   On E : EAccessViolation do 
     // Violação de acesso
     // Tratar esse erro aqui 

   On E: EExternalException do
     // Erro Interno
     // Tratar esse erro aqui.
   else
     ShowMessage('Erro desconhecido. Contate o administrador do sistema.');
end;
```

Porém, se você quiser impedir que exceções sejam lançadas pelo [*Debugger*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depurador), faça o seguinte rota:

`Tools` → `Options` → `Debugger Options` → `Language Exceptions`, **desabilite** a caixa de verificação `Notify on language exceptions`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]